# Sending out email notification for Jenkins build for a particular builds

Tags: java, email, build, jenkins, automation

I have a Jenkins job which build server different types of products.

Only for some of the products am I interested in receiving an email notification whether the build failed or not.

Different parameters are passed to builds within Jenkins including "product", "releaseBranch" etc.

How can I selectively receive emails based on type of product I am building? Does Jenkins have a plugin for this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to create a separate Jenkins job (project) for each product. This would have the advantage that you could look at the build history for each job and know immediately which product was built by a given build.

Comment: That is indeed what is happening. I spawn of new job every time is build is submitted. I however cannot have separate "stacks" of jobs if thats what you are intending. So I am still confused how to extract build information out of a job and based on that send out a email notification. Thanks.

Comment: By "job" I mean the job definition (sometimes referred to as a project) that defines where the source code is located, how to build and publish it, etc. - e.g. http://jenkins/job/myjob I think when you refer to spawning new jobs you are talking about a build of a job, e.g. http://jenkins/job/myjob/6.  I'm suggesting that instead of paramterizing a single job to build multiple products, you create a separate job for each product.  That's much simpler to maintain and understand.

Comment: Would https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin help you do that for each job? i.e. when a job fails, send an email to certain group etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Editable Email Notification" plugin and add the trigger named "Script". Here you can write a groovy script which can decide the email notification to be sent or not.